# Order a List in Map java

Tags: java

So i have a Armstrong List = " [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 153, 370, 371, 407] "

And i am trying to put it in a Map like this " {1=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 3=[153, 370, 371, 407]} "

My Code:

```
    public static Map<Integer, List<Integer>> groupByLength(List<Integer> list){
        Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = new TreeMap<Integer, List<Integer>>();
        List<Integer> neu = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        String s = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            s = list.get(i) + "";
            if(map.containsKey(s.length())) {
                neu.add(list.get(i));
            }
            else {
                map.put(s.length(), neu);
                neu.clear();
            }
            s = "";
        }
        return map;
    }
```

My problem is, if i change the list (neu), the list in the map will change too

**Output**

```
{1=[370, 371, 407], 3=[370, 371, 407]}
```

Comment: With Java 8 stream support your methods body can be reduced to: `return list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(nr -> nr.toString().length()));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your map has Key-Value pairs and you need to be adding elements to the list that is the **Value**. If your map doesn't have the Key-Value pair, then you need to **instantiate a new list**, add a value to it and `put` it in the map. The method [`getOrDefault()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-) is very helpful in this case because it lets you get the **Value** list or create a new one into which you can add values:

```
public static Map<Integer, List<Integer>> groupByLength(List<Integer> list){
    Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = new TreeMap<Integer, List<Integer>>();
    for(Integer el : list) {
        int key = el.toString().length();
        List<Integer> value = map.getOrDefault(key, new ArrayList<Integer>());
        value.add(el);
        map.put(key, value);
    }
    return map;
}
```

Edit: A "fancier" at first sight but quite clever optimization as suggested by [*Pshemo*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1393766/pshemo). You can find the same example in the documentation for [`computeIfAbsent()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-)

```
public static Map<Integer, List<Integer>> groupByLength(List<Integer> list){
    Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = new TreeMap<Integer, List<Integer>>();
    for(Integer el : list) {
        int key = el.toString().length();
        map.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(el);
    }
    return map;
}
```

Comment: Small nitpick: while executing `getOrDefault(.., new ..)` we will always end up creating new ArrayList regardless if key exists of not. Instead we can use `List<Integer> value = map.computeIfAbsent(key, nrKey -> new ArrayList<>());` since (1) lambdas are usually cached so `key -> new ArrayList<>()` in each iteration will be same cached object; (2) it will ensure that `value` list will be in map which eliminates need to `map.put(key, value);`. Also `value.add(el);` can be inlined since it will be only place using that list: `map.computeIfAbsent(key, nrKey -> new ArrayList<>()).add(el);`.